# TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of null

Tags: maximo, maximo-anywhere

I have just upgraded to Maximo Anywhere 7.6.1 and in trying to create a follow-up work order from within the Inspection app I get the error below.  The strange thing is that I can create a follow-up workorder from the Work Execution app, and as far as I know the Inspection app pulls through and uses the same source code to do the follow-up work order.

```
    Logger.js:293 === Global promise rejection handling ===writeToLog @    Logger.js:293log @ Logger.js:397error @ Logger.js:415(anonymous function) @     Startup.js:60_f32 @ dojo.js:2_7c8 @ dojo.js:2then._7d5.then @     dojo.js:2otherwise @ dojo.js:2(anonymous function) @ ModelDataSet.js:1045_7c8 @ dojo.js:2_7c2 @ dojo.js:2resolve @ dojo.js:2onSuccess @ _SimulatorConnectivityChecker.js:40onConnectSuccess @ worklight.js:8574bound @ worklight.js:1029onSuccess @ worklight.js:3793onWlSuccess @ worklight.js:3766bound @ worklight.js:1029respondToReadyState @ worklight.js:1287onStateChange @ worklight.js:1209bound @ worklight.js:1029
Logger.js:293 === handled: truewriteToLog @ Logger.js:293log @ Logger.js:397error @ Logger.js:415(anonymous function) @ Startup.js:61_f32 @ dojo.js:2_7c8 @ dojo.js:2then._7d5.then @ dojo.js:2otherwise @ dojo.js:2(anonymous function) @ ModelDataSet.js:1045_7c8 @ dojo.js:2_7c2 @ dojo.js:2resolve @ dojo.js:2onSuccess @ _SimulatorConnectivityChecker.js:40onConnectSuccess @ worklight.js:8574bound @ worklight.js:1029onSuccess @ worklight.js:3793onWlSuccess @ worklight.js:3766bound @ worklight.js:1029respondToReadyState @ worklight.js:1287onStateChange @ worklight.js:1209bound @ worklight.js:1029
Logger.js:293 === Error: Cannot read property 'get' of nullwriteToLog @ Logger.js:293log @ Logger.js:397error @ Logger.js:415(anonymous function) @ Startup.js:64_f32 @ dojo.js:2_7c8 @ dojo.js:2then._7d5.then @ dojo.js:2otherwise @ dojo.js:2(anonymous function) @ ModelDataSet.js:1045_7c8 @ dojo.js:2_7c2 @ dojo.js:2resolve @ dojo.js:2onSuccess @ _SimulatorConnectivityChecker.js:40onConnectSuccess @ worklight.js:8574bound @ worklight.js:1029onSuccess @ worklight.js:3793onWlSuccess @ worklight.js:3766bound @ worklight.js:1029respondToReadyState @ worklight.js:1287onStateChange @ worklight.js:1209bound @ worklight.js:1029
Logger.js:293 TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of null
    at Object.resolveWonumLabel (WOListHandler.js:210)
    at Object.getMessage (DynamicMessage.js:38)
    at Object.getPropertyString (_ControlBase.js:171)
    at Object.getLabelString (_ControlBase.js:163)
    at Object.setLabel (View.js:445)
    at Object.<anonymous> (View.js:239)
    at Object.<anonymous> (dojo.js:2)
    at _1293 (dojo.js:2)
    at Object._1290._watchCallbacks (dojo.js:2)
    at dojo.js:2
```